# .NET Maui Labels in VerticalStackLayout in a CollectionView not wrapping according the LineBreakMode

Tags: maui, .net-maui

I have a HorizontalStackLayout with an image and a VerticalStackLayout containing a Label to hold my Subject. If I use a smaller device I would the Subject to be wrapped accoording to the width of the device and the Labels LineBreakMode. But this is not happend.

If I manually set the width of the VerticalStackLayout the Subject is wrapped but I want this to be automaticly done.

What have I missed or done wrong?

Using VS 2022 v17.3.0 Preview 4.0

My code look like this:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:model ="clr-namespace:fotbollz.Model"
             x:Class="fotbollz.MainPage">

    <CollectionView>
        <CollectionView.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type model:NewsItem}">
                <model:NewsItem Created="2022-07-27" Updated="2022-07-27 12:15"  
                                Subject="ÖFK klar för Allsvenskan igen och man är jätteglada!"  
                                Author="Firstname Lastname" 
                                ClubLogo="https://fotbollz.se/_upload/teams/logo/ofk_logo.gif" />
                <model:NewsItem Created="2022-07-27 14:02" Updated="2022-07-27 12:15"  Subject="Min rubrik2"  Author="Firstname Lastname" ClubLogo="https://fotbollz.se/_upload/teams/logo/ofk_logo.gif" />
                <model:NewsItem Created="2022-07-27 12:03" Updated="2022-07-27 12:15"  Subject="Ytterhogdal vinner igen!"  Author="Firstname Lastname" ClubLogo="https://fotbollz.se/_upload/teams/logo/ytterhogdal_logo.gif" />
                <model:NewsItem Created="2022-07-27 12:04" Updated="2022-07-27 12:15"  Subject="Min rubrik4"  Author="Firstname Lastname" ClubLogo="https://fotbollz.se/_upload/teams/logo/ifk_logo.gif" />
                <model:NewsItem Created="2022-07-27 12:05" Updated="2022-07-27 12:15"  Subject="Häggenås spelade oavgjort!"  Author="Myggan Handler" ClubLogo="https://fotbollz.se/_upload/teams/logo/haggenas.png" />
            </x:Array>
        </CollectionView.ItemsSource>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:NewsItem">
                <HorizontalStackLayout Padding="5">
                    <!-- This is the url to the club logo-->
                    <Image Source="{Binding ClubLogo}" HeightRequest="75" WidthRequest="75" Aspect="AspectFill" />

                    <!-- This is the Subject author and created date of the news 
                    Problem: Why isn't the long text wrapped as described in LineBreakMode. If I set  WidthRequest="275" then the text is wrapped.
                    -->
                    <VerticalStackLayout Padding="5" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Subject}" FontSize="14" LineBreakMode="MiddleTruncation" MaxLines="1" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                        <Label FontSize="12" >
                            <Label.Text>
                                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm} Av: {1}">
                                    <Binding Path="Created" />
                                    <Binding Path="Author" />
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Label.Text>
                        </Label>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Ingress}" FontSize="18" />

                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                </HorizontalStackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</ContentPage>
```

The attached image shows the result: on the left is what I want and the picture on the right is what I get: [What I want and what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LY9QW.png)

Comment: Looks like a bug in dynamic layout. If you set a fixed `WidthRequest="200"` (or whatever) on `VerticalStackLayout`, does it get it correct? [I realize that probably isn't desireable, but it will determine what the bug is.] And is this testing on Local Machine (Windows) or a mobile emulator?

Comment: Yes, if I set a fixed width it works. I get the same 'bug' if I run on Windows machine.

Comment: ok, then that is the work-around for now. I recommend opening a [maui issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues) describing the problem. Show code above. Mention platforms tested on. Ideally, make a public github repo with minimum code required to run and show the problem. That makes it much easier for devs to determine the cause and fix it.

Comment: I started with looking at James Montemagno course on get started with Maui; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DuNLR_NJv8U&t=1915s.

In his MonkeyFinder app I can start with the solution in Part 2 and just change the name of the monkey to a longer name and add a LineBreakMode to get this error. 

I will see how to file an issue. Thanks for your time!